# SQL Server database won't work on different PC

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, vb.net

I've created a Windows Forms app with a SQL Server database file (`.mdf`) that works perfectly on my computer.

When I created the installer and I've installed it on a different PC the app stopped working and shows this error:

> ERROR 50 Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance

I've already installed SQL Server Express Management on the second PC, but the version is 11 and on my first PC I've 13

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance

Sounds like you need to install SQL Server Express Edition, the [LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017) package from [SQL Server Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)